# Using same variable inside and outside loop

Tags: php, wordpress

On my blog page I have a loop that uses custom template for displaying posts, `content-blog.php`.

`content-blog.php` is also used for rendering the messages Infinite Scroll fetches. It displays messages from category `Twitter` in one way and all other messages in other.

I want to add extra class to first post that is not in category `Twitter` to achieve this

```
twitter

twitter

any-other.extraclass

any-other

any-other

twitter

twitter

any-other.extraclass

any-other
```

Or add extra class to last `Twitter` to achieve this

```
twitter

twitter.extraclass

any-other

any-other

any-other

twitter

twitter.extraclass

any-other

any-other
```

I have figured that a structure in `home.php`

```
<?php $flag = 0; ?> 
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php if (has_category( 'Twitter' )): ?>
     stuff done..
     <?php $flag = 1; ?>    
  <?php else: ?>
     stuff done and extra glass given if $flag == 1
     <?php $flag = 0; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Works but it does not work when using a separate template part.

```
<?php $flag = 0; ?> 
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' ); ?>

  --content-blog.php--

  <?php if (has_category( 'Twitter' )): ?>
     stuff done..
     <?php $flag = 1; ?>    
  <?php else: ?>
     stuff done and extra glass given if $flag == 1
     <?php $flag = 0; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

-- /content-blog.php --

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: Please make sure to mention what you mean by `this` when you say `achieve this` its not very clear.  Your question is not very clear in the classes part why are you mentioning the list of classes needs to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Today i learned the difference between local variable scope and global variable scope. After setting the variable in functions.php and declaring $flag global everything worked.

```
--content-blog.php--

<?php global $flag; ?>  

<?php if (has_category( 'Twitter' )): ?>
   stuff done..
   <?php $flag = 1; ?>    
<?php else: ?>
   stuff done and extra glass given if $flag == 1
   <?php $flag = 0; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

-- /content-blog.php --
```